# ¿Cómo definir la altura en Jquery Panorama Viewer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo el script de `jQuery`, [Panorama Viewer](https://github.com/peachananr/panorama_viewer), funcionando en mi sitio, pero el problema es que me toma la altura que tiene la imagen (`1000px`) y por ende la imagen acapara todo el espacio de la pantalla, por lo que quisiera reducirlo. El código está en su repositorio de GitHub pero aquí les pongo el código.

```
    !function($){
  var defaults = {
    repeat: false,
    direction: "horizontal",
        animationTime: 700,
        easing: "ease-out",
        overlay: true
    };

  function Timer(callback, delay) {
      var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

      this.pause = function() {
          window.clearTimeout(timerId);
          remaining -= new Date() - start;
      };

      this.resume = function() {
          start = new Date();
          timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
      };

      this.resume();
  }

    function touchHandler(event)
  {
      var touches = event.changedTouches,
          first = touches[0],
          type = "";

           switch(event.type)
      {
          case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
          case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
          case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
          default: return;
      }

      var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");

      var mult = 2;

      if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ) {
          mult = 10
      }

      simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                                first.screenX, first.screenY,
                                (first.clientX * mult), (first.clientY * mult), false,
                                false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);
      first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
  }
  $.fn.panorama_viewer = function(options){

    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);

    return this.each(function(){
      var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options),
      el = $(this);

      el.imagesLoaded(function () {
        el.find("> img").addClass("pv-pano");
        el.addClass("pv-container").wrapInner("<div class='pv-inner pv-animating'></div>");

        if (settings.direction == "vertical") {
           el.addClass("pv-vertical")
        }

        el.find(".pv-animating").css({
          "-webkit-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
          "-moz-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
          "-ms-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
          "transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing
        })
        imgSrc = el.find(".pv-pano").attr("src")
        width = el.find(".pv-pano").width()
        height = el.find(".pv-pano").height()
        var repeat = "no-repeat";
        if (settings.repeat == true) {
          repeat = "repeat"
        }

        el.find(".pv-inner").css({
          height: height,
          width: width,
          background: "url(" + imgSrc + ") " + repeat,
          "background-size": "cover"
        })

        if (settings.overlay == true) {
          $("<div class='pv-overlay'><i class='pvicon-overlay'></i></div>").appendTo(el.find(".pv-inner"))

          el.find(".pv-inner").bind("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).find(".pv-overlay ").fadeOut("fast");
          }).bind("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).find(".pv-overlay ").fadeIn("fast");
          })
        }


        var $bg = el.find(".pv-inner"),
        elbounds = {
          w: parseInt($bg.parent().width()),
          h: parseInt($bg.parent().height())
        },
        bounds = {w: width - elbounds.w, h: height - elbounds.h},
        origin = {x: 0, y: 0},
        start = {x: 0, y: 0},
        movecontinue = false;

        function move (e){

          var inbounds = {x: false, y: false},
              offset = {
                  x: start.x - (origin.x - e.clientX),
                  y: start.y - (origin.y - e.clientY)
              };
          if (settings.direction == "horizontal") {
            if (settings.repeat == true) {
              inbounds.x = true;
            } else {
              inbounds.x = offset.x < 0 && (offset.x * -1) < bounds.w;
            }

            if (movecontinue && inbounds.x) {
                start.x = offset.x;
                start.y = 0;
            }
          } else {
            if (settings.repeat == true) {
              inbounds.y = true;
            } else {
              inbounds.y = offset.y < 0 && (offset.y * -1) < bounds.h;
            }

            if (movecontinue && inbounds.y) {
                start.y = offset.y;
                start.x = 0;
            }
          }

          $(this).css('background-position', start.x + 'px ' + start.y + 'px');


          origin.x = e.clientX;
          origin.y = e.clientY;

          e.stopPropagation();
          return false;
        }

        function handle (e){
            movecontinue = false;
            $bg.unbind('mousemove', move);

            if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
                origin.x = e.clientX;
                origin.y = e.clientY;
                movecontinue = true;
                $bg.bind('mousemove', move);
            } else {
              $(document.body).focus();
            }

            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }

        function reset (){
            start = {x: 0, y: 0};
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
        }


        $bg.bind('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', handle);
        $bg.bind('dblclick', reset);

        el.find(".pv-pano").hide()
      })


    });

  }

}(window.jQuery);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sí la librería se adapta siempre al alto de la imagen, entonces basta con cambiar la altura de la imagen con CSS.

Comment: ¡Hola Gustavo!
Fíjate que ya intenté eso, con css, y cambiando del código del JS la propiedad de height, pero no funciona :/ Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo el código de dicha librería, pude cambiar el tamaño de la imagen. Hay dos clases que debes modificar ligeramente:

- panorama
- pv-inner

**Ejemplo**

```js
$(".panorama").panorama_viewer({
  repeat: false,
  direction: "horizontal",
  animationTime: 700,
  easing: "ease-out",
  overlay: true
});
```

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center
}

.panorama {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80%;
}

.panorama>.pv-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/peachananr/panorama_viewer/84488596/jquery.panorama_viewer.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/peachananr/panorama_viewer/84488596/panorama_viewer.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="panorama">
  <img src="http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/panorama_viewer/demo_photo5.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

---

Lo único que debes cambiar es `height` en ambas clases. Para `.panorama` debe ser un alto específico (el que desees) y para `.pv-inner` debe ser `100%`.

---

**PD**: Ejecuta varias veces el código porque parece que hay problemas con la sincronización.

Comment: ¡Funcionó! ¡Muchas gracias!